# Existence of Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given two homomorphisms $\alpha$ : **A** $\rightarrow$ **B** and $\beta$ : **A** $\rightarrow$ **C**, if $\ker( \beta ) \subseteq \ker( \alpha )$ and $\beta$ is onto (surjective), show that there is a homomorphism $\gamma$ : **C** $\rightarrow$ **B** such that $\alpha = \gamma \circ \beta$.

I guess it's the more universal problem like [Existence of Homomorphism so that Diagram Commutes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605863/existence-of-homomorphism-so-that-diagram-commutes) - but here with the surjective property. According to the comments there, it should be an easy proof then, but I'm not familiar with showing the existence of an homomorphism plus it's property to extend. Any ideas? The proof with groups or maybe rings might help here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique you want to follow is an elementary form of what is called *diagram chasing*: pick a $c \in C$, since $\beta$ is surjective, you can find an $a \in A$ with $\beta(a)=c$. Now define $\gamma: C \rightarrow B$, by $\gamma(c)=\alpha(a)$. You have to show that $\gamma$ is a well-defined homomorphism - it does not depend on the particular choice of $a$. This last fact is guaranteed by the inclusion $ker(\beta) \subseteq ker(\alpha)$. And almost by definition, $\alpha=\gamma \circ \beta$.

Comment: $\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & \xrightarrow{\quad} & \ker(\alpha) & \xrightarrow{\quad} & A & \xrightarrow[\quad]{\alpha} & B \\
& & \uparrow & & \| & & ~\uparrow\rlap{\!\gamma} \\
0 & \xrightarrow{\quad} & \ker(\beta) & \xrightarrow{\quad} & A & \xrightarrow[\quad]{\beta} & C & \xrightarrow{\quad} & 0
\end{array}$I made you a diagram for the chase :-)

Comment: Right! Thanks, and @cbb: good hunting! :-)

Comment: Wow, i'm impressed - thanks a lot! I have to think about that a bit - the part with the surjection is clear, but I can't really see the connection to the kernel property - what is the problem if the size of the kernels would be the other way round?

From my understanding, the one with the "bigger" kernel has the smaller image - in this case, B should be smaller/equal than C - therefore it sounds reasonable to assume I can get to B over C. But, that doesn't sound very mathematical. ;-)

Comment: Hint: suppose $\beta(a)=c$, but also $\beta(a')=c$, where both $a, a' \in A$. What can you say about $a^{-1}a'$?

Comment: Isn't $^{-1}$ a specific operation which might or might not be in my algebra?

But besides that, I would say that $\gamma(\beta(a)) = \gamma(\beta(a'))$ - therefore it doesn't depend of my choice of a? But this doesn't really use the kernel.

Comment: @cbb Yes you are right - but the notion of a *kernel* implies the existence of a neutral element, $0$ in case of a commutative algebra (ring, module over a ring, ..), but it is also written as $1$ in a multiplicative case. So I could have written $a'-a$. Now, if $\beta(a)=c=\beta(a')$, then $\beta(a-a')=0$, so $a-a' \in ker(\beta)$, whence $a-a' \in ker(\alpha)$. So $\gamma(c)=\alpha(a)=\alpha(a')$, showing independence of the choice of $a$! Got it?

Comment: I got it! I had to translate it to our definition of a kernel, and it get's even easier to understand! Thank you so much! Our kernel is: $ker(\alpha) = \{<a,b> \in A^2 : \alpha(a) = \alpha(b)\}$

Now: $\forall c \in \mathcal{C} \exists a \in \mathcal{A}$ with $ \beta(a) = c$

Let $\gamma : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ be definded through $\gamma(c)=\alpha(a)$

Proof: $\gamma$ is well-defined:
For $a, a' \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\beta(a)=\beta(a')$
$\Rightarrow <a,a'> \in ker \beta$
$\Rightarrow <a,a'> \in ker \alpha$
$\Rightarrow \gamma(c) = \alpha(a) = \alpha(a')$

Comment: @cbb Yes that is it! If you deem my answer as the right one please be so kind to tick it as such. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! Is the tick right? Wanted to vote for it, but thats not possible yet. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can somebody help me show that $\gamma(c_1 + c_2) = \gamma(c_1) + \gamma(c_2)$ under the previous definition of gamma?

Comment: @Mathematical Mushroom: This follows from the fact that $\gamma$ is defined with the help of $\alpha$ which happens to be a homomorphism.